# Не могу удалить элемент из json в node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Я получаю с mongodb такой вот Array JSON:

```
[{
    "_id": "0",
    "title": "title0",
    "about": "about0",
    "__v": 0,
    "created": "time",
    "content_like": {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "user1"
    }
}, {
    "_id": "1",
    "title": "title1",
    "about": "about1",
    "__v": 0,
    "created": "time",
    "content_like": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "user2"
    }
}, {
    "_id": "2",
    "title": "title2",
    "about": "about2",
    "__v": 0,
    "created": "time",
    "content_like": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "user3"
    }
}]
```

Я пытаюсь удалить ненужные мне элементы:

```
modelEvent.find({}, function(error, event) {
    if (error) return next(error);
    if (event) {
       for (var i = 0; i < event.length; i++) {
         delete event[i]['__v'];
         delete event[i]['content_like'];
         delete event[i]['created'];
       }
       console.log(event);
       response.send(200, event);
    }
});
```

Но я получаю аналогичный массив json со всеми полями что и были.
В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: JSON это строка - а вы получаете обычный массив

Comment: что выводит `console.log(event);`?

Comment: В 'console.log(event);' выводится весь полученный json c mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1. Явно укажите поля для выборки

[`Model.find(query, fields, options, callback)`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/finding-documents.html) имеет необязательные параметры, `fields` и `options`. Вам поможет `fields`, он указывает, какие поля брать/не брать в результат. Задать его можно двумя равносильными способами - строкой `"title about"` или объектом `{title:1,about:1}`

Код примет вид:

```
modelEvent.find({}, {title:1,about:1}, function(error, event) {
   if(error) return next(error);
   console.log(event);
   response.send(200, event);
});
```

#### 2. `.map()` - преобразование элементов массива.

В аналогичных ситуациях для изменения/удаление полей каждого элемента результатов я использовал `.map()`

Код примет вид:

```
modelEvent.find({}, function(error, event) {
   if (error) return next(error);
   if (event) event=event.map(function(e){
      return {_id:e._id, title:e.title, about:e.about};
   });
   console.log(event);
   response.send(200, event);
});
```

Comment: `{e._id, e.title, e.about}` синтаксическая ошибка?

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо, очепятка, ctrl+del съел ключи) поправил

Comment: Спасибо большое, помог первый способ, я выбрал поля которые мне нужны и цикл теперь не нужен)))